# How can I take screenshot of screen when it is not on display stack? Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to make screen transition from **my_screen1** to **my_screen2**. Idea is to take screenshot of both screens, and with animation to transit from 1 to 2. And then to push my_screen2 on display stack.  But can I take screenshot of screen my_screen2 *before* I push it on display stack?
the code:

```
 Display.screenshot(bitmap);
```

gives screenshot of screen which is *already* on display. Is there something like:

```
 my_screen2.screenshot(bitmap);
```

Any example code please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to take the screen shot of previous screen, then do like this as.. First take one bitmap as static in second screen and then in first Screen take the screenshot of present screen and assign that bitmap to the static bitmap(which is declared as static in second screen) then pop the present screen and go to next screen then you have the previous screen in the second screen; If I understood is wrong then give us clear idea;

Comment: @alishaik786 hmm i like your idea - "have the previous screen in the second screen". but .. whats then? So ok i have bitmap of first screen in second screen but in order to make video of sliding transition i still need bitmap of next screen so that user could see second screen 'sliding in' . at which point should i take screenshot of it?

Comment: my idea was to have two bitmaps and make a simple video of sliding one bitmap to another. question is at which point should i take second bitmap shot?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot take screenshot of a screen which is not on the display stack ,or which is below a particular screen. The docs say that `Display.screenshot()` **Takes a screenshot of the entire screen and saves it into a Bitmap.**

If you want to have a screen transition animation to go from one screen to another, you can do the following.

```
UiEngineInstance engine = Ui.getUiEngineInstance();

                    TransitionContext transitionContextPush = new TransitionContext(
                            TransitionContext.TRANSITION_SLIDE);
                    transitionContextPush.setIntAttribute(
                            TransitionContext.ATTR_DURATION, 150);
                    transitionContextPush.setIntAttribute(
                            TransitionContext.ATTR_DIRECTION,
                            TransitionContext.DIRECTION_LEFT);

                    TransitionContext transitionContextPop = new TransitionContext(
                            TransitionContext.TRANSITION_SLIDE);
                    transitionContextPop.setIntAttribute(
                            TransitionContext.ATTR_DURATION, 150);
                    transitionContextPop.setIntAttribute(
                            TransitionContext.ATTR_DIRECTION,
                            TransitionContext.DIRECTION_RIGHT);
                    transitionContextPop.setIntAttribute(
                            TransitionContext.ATTR_KIND,
                            TransitionContext.KIND_OUT);

                    engine.setTransition(null, thisScreen,
                            UiEngineInstance.TRIGGER_PUSH,
                            transitionContextPush);
                    engine.setTransition(thisScreen, null,
                            UiEngineInstance.TRIGGER_POP,
                            transitionContextPop);
                }
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(thisScreen);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am targeting 4.6 devices. your code is good for 5.0 and up...

Comment: You cannot use classes from the 5.0 API in an application built for 4.6 with or without the use of preprocessers.  The only use for preprocessing in this instance would be to exclude any 4.6 specific code when building for 5.0 and above, using the more recent API additons

Comment: Yep. couldnt edit my comment, . for pre os5 he will have to find another way to do the transition. but for os5 onwards he can use my answer. to do that he can use preprocessors.

Comment: I have provided him with a link to a pre-OS5 solution above

Answer (score 4):

See this solution by rahul_narkhede for pre-OS5 Sliding Screen Transitions, I have used it successfully in the past.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Animated-Screen-transitions/td-p/162521/page/6